# swiping items on listview, with small vertical margin

Tags: android, android-listview

So I have a `ListView` on which I attach :

```
mList.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

What this gesture listener does is basically measure deltaX (horizontal swipe) and detects if it is higher than some value, then it knows that swipe has occured.

Then I have :

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { ... }
```

Which checks with gesture object if swipe has happened, if yes its a swipe, otherwise its a click.

All this works fine.

**My issue is :**

When I swipe elements with my thumb, sometimes I make a list scroll just a bit vertically.
The horizontal swipe is detected, but the problem is that `OnItemClickListener` doesnt fire, which is where I would launch some actions on the item depending if it is a swipe or not.

So the problem is that the vertical scroll mechanism of listview, makes something that makes onItemClicked event not to fire.

[image]

the list on the left works fine, no vertical scrolling appears.
the list on the right, I swipe the item but slightly to the bottom as well (still within the bounds of this item) so that the list moves just a bit. And the `OnItemClicked` does not fire.

How can I add a small margin for vertical scroll, so that the scroll appears but the onItemClicked is still fired?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for implementation of swiping a listview, 
now when in December edition of Gmail there is a swiping effect on each item, its implementation answers my question

It can be found here :

https://gist.github.com/2980593