# Swipers(Horizontal swiper) in listview(vertical scroller), not working with nested Loop Jquery Mobile

Tags: android, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, swiper.js

I am trying to achieve this horizontal swipers inside listview(vertical scroll) in Jquery Mobile, below i attached an example of what i meant but that is in Android. I am wondering how would i achieve this in Jquery Mobile. It is the functionality in Airbnb app - a listview that you can scroll vertically, but at the same time each list has multiple images that you can scroll horizontally.

[swiping items on listview, with small vertical margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912061/swiping-items-on-listview-with-small-vertical-margin)

I had an attempt to achieve it by loading the list in an ajax, and then nest the images inside another for loop and putting that into swipers. But the problem is the swiper isnt showing up, and also the layout is all messed up.

```
<script>
     $( "#form" ).submit('pageinit',function( event ) {
          $("#newContent2").empty();
          var values = $(this).serialize();
         console.log(values);
                $.ajax({
   type: "POST",

   url: "http://test.com/search.php",
   data: values,
                  dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){ 
               console.log(data);

    var $el = $('#list');
    var listView = new infinity.ListView($el);

    for (var i=0; i<50; i++) {
        var listing = data[i].listing;
        var Location = data[i].Location;
        var date = data[i].date;     

        var images = data[i].pics.split(',');
        console.log(image);

         for(var j = 0; j<images.length; j++){

       var image3=  "http://test.com/"+images;
        console.log(image3);

                    var image2=" <div class='swiper-slide'><img class='lazy' src='"+ image3 + "' width='100%'  id='viewer'/></div>"

         }

         var myOtherUrl = "list.html?Listingid="  + encodeURIComponent(listingid)+"?Location="+ encodeURIComponent(Location)+ encodeURIComponent(nobed+"?date="+ encodeURIComponent(date));

        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", "#pageX", { foo: data[i].listingid, location:data[i].Location } );

        var $newContent = "<li id='indi'><a href='" + myOtherUrl + "'>'"+ image2+ "'</a></li>"             

        +"<div id=two class=col-md-1 style=height:38%> <h9 class=name data-address  href='"+ myOtherUrl +  "'><a id="+"my-button"+">BucketListly</a>"+ "<h9 >&nbsp"+data[i].Location+ "</h9>";

        $("#newContent2").append($newContent);

    var listItems = listView.find('.my-items');
        for(var index = 0, length = listItems.length; index < length; index++) {
            listItems[index].remove();
        }

          var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        loop:false,
      autoResize: true,
    calculateHeight:true,
        onSlideChangeStart: function(){
            $('.swiper-pagination-switch').removeClass('active')
            $('.swiper-pagination-switch').eq(swiper.activeSlide).addClass('active')
        }
    });

    //navigation
    $('.swiper-pagination-switch').click(function(){
        swiper.swipeTo($(this).index());
        $('.swiper-pagination-switch').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active')
    })

    }
           }
            });
          return false;
  });    

        </script>
```

Comment: You could do it with Iscroll 5 using free scroll. -- http://iscrolljs.com/ --  Problem is you gonna have a lot of scrollers, one for each li item. anyway this is a demo for you. --- http://jsfiddle.net/y6pt4Lgf/

Comment: sweet, i think thats what i am looking for, but just wondering can i put swiper inside each li in the iscroll5? Or would i just include the images in the li? Because i am trying to have the snap to image function as well, like in a swiper.

Comment: You wont need swiper if you use iscroll. You could put your images in a table inside the list items. demo .. http://jsfiddle.net/6ua74umo/..  Check the settings for iscroll, i made some modifications, seems you dont need to free scroll, but just scroll on the x axis. There is another nice demo i found that scrolls both ways of row of images. http://jsfiddle.net/8BUjf/2/

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for the help http://jsfiddle.net/y6pt4Lgf/2/, i tried to modify the example from the iscroll site, i kind of can manage to make what i am looking for, but i am having  aproblem, i am trying to initialize the plugin and assign it to class instead of id var myScroll = new IScroll('.wrapper') but only the first wrapper will scroll.

Comment: Only 1 div can be assigned to the class, not sure if it is me doing something wrong.

Comment: You have to initialize wrapper2 as its a new scroller. Also check the CSS you need to change from ID to class. demo http://jsfiddle.net/LxLhzotz/